# What are the dangers of using subqueries with IN clauses?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, in-clause

I recently uncovered a query (which has since been lost) that seemed to have an issue stemming from the use of a subquery alongside an IN clause. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 IN (SELECT Column1 FROM Table2)
```

The issue I seemed to notice was that when I used IN and NOT IN, the figures with each did not account for the total records in Table1. Whilst Table1 did not have any NULL values in Column1, I believe that Table2 did. Could this have caused an issue? I appreciate that comparing something to NULL via the standard logical operators will not work in T-SQL, but I have not been able to find anything regarding IN clauses with subqueries.

I unfortunately do not have the original query, and when I tried to reproduce the issue using some very general code, I could not. So I appreciate this is perhaps a vague question, but it would be useful to know of any 'dangers' that people may not be generally aware of when using the IN/NOT IN operators with a subquery, specifically relating to NULLS. Any other general dangers not necessarily relating to NULLS would also be useful.

I would assume the general advice would be to use a JOIN, however this is primarily so that I can identify possible issues in existing code and remediate if necessary.

Comment: You should read this article which explains the differences of these very well. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/08/17/exists-vs-in/

Answer (score 0):

The following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 NOT IN (SELECT Column1 FROM Table2)
```

Will never return any rows *if* `Table2.Column1` is ever `NULL`.  Why?  Well, if `Column1` matches a value in `Table2`, then the expression returns false.  If `Column1` does not match a value, then you have the comparison to `NULL` -- and that comparison returns `NULL`.

My advice is to use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Column1 FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.Column1 = t1.Column1)
```

This has the more expected behavior.

You *can* use `JOIN`, but that runs the risk of producing duplicate rows.